# How to get values after an equal sign

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a file delimited with space and random column ordering as follows:

```
name=Joan age=42 ip=172.20.1.80 sex=M loc=UK 
loc=IR sex=F ip=172.20.1.1 age=32 name=Sandra
```

I want to extract specific fields (`name`, `loc`, and `ip`) only.

So the result that I'm looking for is as follows:

```
Joan|UK|172.20.1.80
Sandra|IR|172.20.1.1
```

Comment: Similar (if you just replace the space with newline), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571739/parsing-variables-from-config-file-in-bash

Comment: @michael Not quite. You need something to detect the different "blocks" then if the input has more that one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, your input file has a format the shell understands when it comes to
assigning variables a value: `var1=value1 var2=value2` etc. So we can simply
read each line and use the `eval` command to *evaluate* the line.

Put the following into a file, say `parse.sh`, do `chmod +x parse.sh` and
run it with your input file as a parameter.

Script `parse.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
    eval $line;
    echo "$name|$loc|$ip"
done < "$1"

exit 0;
```

File `input.txt`:

```
name=Joan age=42 ip=172.20.1.80 sex=M loc=UK
loc=IR sex=F ip=172.20.1.1 age=32 name=Sandra
```

Run:

```
me@ubuntu:~> ./parse.sh input.txt 
Joan|UK|172.20.1.80
Sandra|IR|172.20.1.1
```

---

Please note that the values must not have a space in them. E.g.

```
ip=... name=Ubai salih loc=...
```

would not work and give syntax errors. Also, if the input file would contain a line with a `bad_command` that command gets executed because that is how `eval` works: it just executes the given string.

Comment: Die to the risk if code injection (malicious or accidentally), I might prefer a different solution.

Comment: @michael Yes, you are right. I added a note to the answer to mention that. Another possibility would be to split at spaces and then at `=`. Or pick `name=\S+` etc. with a regex. Feel invited to post another approach ;-)

Comment: @michael **Due to the risk *of ...* Too late to edit the comment I know, but just wanted to mention the typos in case anyone else is confused.

Comment: Oh goodness, sorry, I just noticed the typo (I blame autocorrect). Code injection is bad, but only on rare occasion lethal.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a Python solution like [PerlDuck's Bash solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113261/301745), but not evaluating the input.

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    record = line.rstrip('\n')
    d = dict(kv.split('=') for kv in record.split(' '))
    print(d['name'], d['loc'], d['ip'], sep='|')
```

Run:

```
$ ./parse.py input.txt
Joan|UK|172.20.1.80
Sandra|IR|172.20.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the output order that you want is reverse lexical (name > loc > ip) you could select and then reverse sort the fields, then remove the `fieldname=` prefixes. For example in Perl:

```
$ perl -alne '
    print join "|", map { s/.*=//r } reverse sort grep { /^(name|loc|ip)=/ } @F
' file
Joan|UK|172.20.1.80
Sandra|IR|172.20.1.1
```