# In arbitrary line of text, how can bash extract a named value after an equal sign?

Tags: bash, regex

This question ([How to get values after an equal sign](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113249/847577)) is basically what I want:

Given a line of text, with named parameter looking syntax like `color=red`, using bash how can you grab that color value (yielding `red`)?

Except in that question, the line of text is entirely those key-value pairs, so the accepted answer utilizes bash's `eval` since that syntax happens fit very nicely.

---

I'm wondering for a generic line of text like `⎜ ↳ Synaptics TM3289-021 id=13 ]` how I could grab that id value (yielding `13`)?

Maybe utilizing regex, where I know the line will contain `[whitespace]id=<TEXT I WANT>[whitespace]`?

Comment: `xinput list --id-only "Logitech USB Receiver Mouse"` you can get the id from xinput directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep`'s `-o` (output only the matched text) option. Read `man grep` and do:

```
echo "bunch of. text id=13 more=4" | \
  grep -E -o 'id=[0-9]+`
```

If you want to be extra careful, match the leading and trailing spaces as well:

```
echo "bunch of. text id=13 more=4" | \
  grep -E -o ' id=[0-9]+ '
```

Comment: Awesome! Then I guess it's easy enough to snag the resulting string starting after the first chars (since "id=" is 3 chars). And I'll also look up how to look for any whitespace around it, not just spaces (my case has tabs I think).

Comment: @tscizzle if you want all numbers from, e.g., id=<n> you can use lookbehind: `grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d+'`

Comment: @tscizzle you can also use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which have `\K` for "ignore whatever was matched up to this point" which lets you do: `grep -oP 'id=\K[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want *bash* to extract the value, you can use a regex with the `=~` operator inside `[[ ... ]]` test brackets ex.:

```
$ re='\bid=([^[:blank:]]*)'
$ line='⎜ ↳ Synaptics TM3289-021 id=13 ]'
$ 
$ [[ $line =~ $re ]] && printf '%d\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
13
```

Note that I used `\b` (a word boundary) rather than whitespace as the start anchor - that allows the expression to match in the case that `id=13` occurs at the start of the line as well as part way through.

If you want to use grep, then I'd suggest making use of GNU grep's perl compatible mode so that you can match but not include the `id=` portion:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\w*'
13
```

or

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -Po 'id=\K\w*'
13
```

Here, `\w*` matches a (possibly empty) sequence of word characters - if ypu want to match numeric IDs only, you can change `\w` to `\d`.